# Why my site still Internal Server Error on mod rewrite URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f

RewriteRule ^test8/([^-]*)$ /test8.php?idval=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/
```

When i tried to access to `example.com/test8/123456`

It's will be `Internal Server Error`

But when i edit .htaccess by add this line on first code line for mod rewrite URL.

```
RewriteRule ^test7/([^-]*)$ /test7.php?idval=$1 [L]
```

like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f

RewriteRule ^test7/([^-]*)$ /test7.php?idval=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test8/([^-]*)$ /test8.php?idval=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/
```

When i tried to access to `example.com/test8/123456` It's work good.

But When i tried to access to `example.com/test7/123456` It's will be `Internal Server Error`

I want to know why still `Internal Server Error` on first code line for mod rewrite URL ? how can i do ?

Comment: I thought `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f` cause the internal error. If you comment it and then try it.

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 RewriteRule is applied after each RewriteCond. To make it for 2 or more RewriteRules, add the following after RewriteCond:

```
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=2]
```

This line allows appling multiple RewriteRules for a single RewriteCond.

So your .htaccess will look like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=2]
RewriteRule ^test7/([^-]*)$ /test7.php?idval=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test8/([^-]*)$ /test8.php?idval=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/
```

Change [S=2] to a required number of RewriteRule that need to be applied accordingly.